# Crystal report clicking event

Tags: vb.net

I want to get a value from crystal report on double click on any column value in crystal.and then open a sub report based on this clicked value.. I am using Visual Studio2005 crystal report.. Is this possible with this version.
Please help if having any idea about this. I have tried a lot of things. But not getting any fruitful solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You shall have to set the sub-report as an on-demand report.